# How to Insert Images inside DIV in this case

Tags: css

Please see the Image here

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=41d9394

As shown there are two sliders on the Image with two arrow marks (Left and Right )

Please tell me how to achive those arrow marks on to My sliders (which is shown here )

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=310bb44

My question is how to achive those Arrow marks on these slider components .

Right now my CSS  code for this is

```
.handle {
   position:relative;
     cursor: pointer;
    background: #eeeeee; 
    border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.zoomHandle {
position:relative;
width:7px;
height:50px;

}
```

and i am using it this way :

```
   this.handles.left = new Element('div', {id: 'leftHandle', 'class': 'handle zoomHandle', style: 'display: none;'});


            this.handles.right = new Element('div', {id: 'rightHandle', 'class': 'handle zoomHandle', style: 'display: none;'});
```

Please help me how to insert this Images

Comment: Thank you , i tried this way 

I cannot use the Code which you suggested 

`
this.handles.left = new Element('div', {id: 'leftHandle', 'class': 'handle zoomHandle1'});
this.handles.right = new Element('div', {id: 'rightHandle', 'class': 'handle zoomHandle2'});
`
and my css 
`
    .zoomHandle 1{
    width:7px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url('Left.png');
    margin: 0px
    
    }
  
    .zoomHandle 2{
    background-image: url('Right.png');
    width:7px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 0px
    
    }
 `
But the Image is not shown , could anybody please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert images in divs, you can do like this:

```
document.getElementById("leftHandle").innerHTML = "<img src=\"your-image-left.png\" />";
document.getElementById("rightHandle").innerHTML = "<img src=\"your-image-right.png\" />";
```